# Template and other files do not update with nitro

Tags: nitro

I am using nitro for the time. Sometimes some templates or other files do not update after saving. It feels very random and I cannot exactly reproduce it. At some point they just don't update. I can restart the host in Docker. This will update it once. It's happening on multiple installs of craft. While others are not affected at all. Just now I created a fresh craft install and it seems to work fine. Then I created another one. And it instantly fails to update the changes I made in the config file.

Craft 3.6.12
Nitro 2.0.7
Docker 3.3.1

I deleted and reinstalled nitro and docker twice. Bumped the docker resources to CPU 4 and Memory 10GB. Removed hosts, added them back. Changed file names. Nothing helped.
Any suggestions what else I could try? I could imagine I am missing something simple …

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: In my case it must be something with MacOS. I messed something up there. But the Craft support team helped me finding a workaround. By disabling "Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing" in the general Docker settings the files refresh again. But Docker becomes very slow.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've installed Nitro on a brand new Mac mini. Not much change to mess up a lot in the OS ;) I will contact support, maybe there is something else going on.